# Latex live preview plugin for Tiddlywiki ?

Tags: online, wysiwyg

I did a search and looked through the "related questions" section before asking this question.

One of the wonderful things about StackExchange is its "typewriter" like live-preview below the text-edit box. Now, I am a bigtime Tiddlywiki user and as other users might know, combining TW with Bob McElrath's jsmath plugin allows you to use TW as a latex notebook. The only thing that could make this situation better (heavenly, in fact) is if there was a plugin for TW which generated live-preview a la StackExchange. If not, does anyone know if this feature is available in some other Wiki platform?

Comment: You say "a latex notebook".  Can you *really* use full LaTeX format?  Or do you actually mean that it renders LaTeX-like **maths** code?

Comment: @AndrewStacey AFAIK its only the math part for now. Eventually I'm sure someone will manage to integrate Latex and TW.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am using Guy Rutenberg's [LaTeX for TiddlyWiki](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2011/06/25/latex-for-tiddlywiki-a-mathjax-plugin) plugin in conjunction with Eric Shulman's [PreviewPlugin](http://www.tiddlytools.com/#PreviewPlugin) (as mentioned previously by Brandon C).

To get these two plug-ins to work together correctly you just need to add one line to the PreviewPlugin code. After installation, and you've confirmed that both plugins are installed and working, edit the PreviewPlugin tiddler and locate the following line in the code (it's at line 60)...

```
wikify(value.replace(/\r/g,),p);
```

*AFTER* that line add this line...

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
```

Save the tiddler, save the wiki, and reload. It should now be working. Jump around and shout "Woot!"

Comment: Brilliant! Haven't looked at SE lately so just saw your answer. "Woot"

Answer (score 1):

There is a live preview plugin for TiddlyWiki http://www.tiddlytools.com/#PreviewPlugin that can be used stand alone in order to provide a nice preview window for TiddlyWiki edits.

Seems to work with JsMath, but I haven't done enough editing with any Tex formulas with it to know if it's 100% bug free.

To install the preview edit your EditorTemplate Tiddler and add the div which contains the preview macro. Check out http://www.tiddlytools.com/#PreviewPluginInfo for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Mediawiki (Wikipedia): http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Enable_TeX

dokuwiki: http://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:latex

though these two plugins appear to render tex equasions, not a live preview like here on TSX.

Comment: TW already has that capability via the jsmath plugin. I mentioned this in the question.